# Set state of object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this factory method that creates functions for each change handler:

```
makeHandleChange = changedProperty => newVal => {
    const newState = { ...this.state, [changedProperty]: newVal };
    this.setState({ ...newState });
  };
```

It is being executed for example like that:

```
onChange={this.makeHandleChange('phoneNumber')}
```

How can I set the state of a property object using this function?

For example I have to `setState` the `info.phoneNumber` property:

```
state = {
    info: {
       phoneNumber: '',
    },
}
```

How can I do that with this `makeHandleChange` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get this to work. One is to update your factory code so that it takes into consideration of nested state properties. The other, and probably the easier way is to pass in the entire nested object when you need to update the state.

For example, if you have a `input` field that updates the `phoneNumber` property nested in `this.state.info`:

```
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => this.makeHandleChange("info")({ ...this.state.info, phoneNumber: e.target.value})}
      value={this.state.phoneNumber}
    />
```

In the object you pass in to the function, make sure you destruct `this.state.info` (i.e. `...this.state.info`) before setting the new value so that none of the other nested properties gets overwritten/removed.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following by destructing your previous `info` state property :

```
makeHandleChange = changedProperty => newVal => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ info: { ...prev.info, [changedProperty]: newVal } }));
};
```

This solution uses the callback version of `setState`.

It does the equivalent of the following code:

```
makeHandleChange = changedProperty => newVal => {
    const { info } = this.state
    this.setState({ info: { ...info, [changedProperty]: newVal }});
};
```